# box-shadow with jquery, the order for the arguments are incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want add some variables for one box shadow:
This order are correct in css
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;

But with jQuery, despite my order :

```
$('#primary-navigation')
  .css('box-shadow', $horizontal+'px '+ $vertical+'px '+$gradient+'px '+ $color );
```

The console in Chrome display, that :

```
element.style {
  box-shadow: rgb(231, 214, 26) 8px 3px 8px;
}
```

The color was not in a right place ?

My full test :

```
var $horizontal; var $vertical; var $gradient; var $color= '';
138     if( $(this).data('shadow') ) {
139       if( $(this).data('shadow') === 'horizontal' ) {
140         //console.log($(this).data('shadow') + ' :: ' + $(this).val() );
141         $color = $(this).parent('div').next().next().next().find('input').val();
142         $horizontal = $(this).val();
143         $vertical = $(this).parent('div').next().find('select').find('option:selected').html();
144         $gradient = $(this).parent('div').next().next().find('select').find('option:selected').html(); 

146          $('#primary-navigation')
147           .css('box-shadow', $horizontal+'px '+ $vertical+'px '+$gradient+'px '+ $color );
148         //console.log( $meta, $(this).val(), $vertical, $gradient, $color);
149       }
```

Thanks

Comment: The browser uses rgb(a) or whatever color it supports, not neccessarily the hex value you set, and that's why colors are hard to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Try correcting your quotes.

The correct way has to be

```
$('#primary-navigation')
  .css('box-shadow', 'apx bpx cpx #color';
```

In your case it is

$('#primary-navigation')
  .css('box-shadow', **a'px ' b'px ' c'px ' color;**

Comment: My code works correctely, it is just no sens, because the order with Firebur are correct, but the shadow work correctly ! I doesn't test yet, in IE.

Thanks